# Look up the email for my current Google application-default credentials (ADC)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, credentials

I set up Google Cloud application-default credentials using `gcloud auth application-default login` but now I can't remember which account I used to log in.

I know that `gcloud auth list` will print out the account I used for `gcloud auth login`, but there's no `gcloud auth application-default list`. How can I check which account is used for my ADC?

Answer (score 8):

By default, `gcloud auth application-default login` includes the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` OAuth scope, so you can access the userinfo API using an access token from your application-default credentials.

Run this command in your terminal:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" \
  https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo
```

Example output:

```
{
  "id": "12345",
  "email": "sophiebits@mydomain.com",
  "verified_email": true,
  "picture": "https://...",
  "hd": "mydomain.com"
}
```